# вывод значения через js

Tags: javascript, html

хочу брать значение дива со страницы, и выводить его через js в консоль (нужно для дальнейшей отправки этого значения через ajax)
но консоль пустая, значение не выводит

вот кусок в js

```
 $(".custom-select__item", this).click(function () {
            selectItem($(this).html(), $(this).attr('data-value'));
            $(context).removeClass('active');
            let carName = $(".custom-select__selected").val();

            console.log(carName);
```

и скриншот со страницы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, зачем этот код, и где у вас в html `data-value`, для того что вы написали в вопросе достаточно этого кода:

```
let carName = $(".custom-select__selected").html();
console.log(carName);
```